# Change attributes of all symlink targets in a directory

Tags: bash, xargs, command-line-arguments

How to change attributes of all symlink targets inside a directory ?

```
/usr/bin/find /mydir -type l | xargs /bin/readlink | /usr/bin/chattr +s
```

piping three commands wont works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/usr/bin/find /mydir -type l -exec /bin/readlink {} \; | xargs -d'\n' /usr/bin/chattr +s
```

This will

1. find the links and return the targets, newline separated, through the `readlink` utility and
2. split incoming arguments on newline and run `chattr` on all targets.

A problem could occur if you have newlines within file names, but that is usually just a hypothetical problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
/usr/bin/find /mydir -type l -exec /usr/bin/chattr +s '{}' \;
```